# How to keep footer always at the bottom of a page?

Tags: html, css, footer

I have an image that is 115px that I want at the very bottom of my page. I searched online how to make it stay at the bottom of the page always and got a lot of complicated answers. I made with code of my own one that works (at least in my browser). I realize it might be an immature way to do it, and wanted to see if there were any potential problems with it. Here is my code

```
<div id="footer" style="position:fixed;top:100%;margin-top:-115px;left:0%;repeat:repeat-x;background:url(http://EXAMPLE.com/images/bottom-border.png);height:115px;width:100%;">
&nbsp;
</div>
```

Comment: If it works, it works. You don't need anyone's approval to build a page the way you want. Just be sure to check it in all the browsers & versions you want to support. `fixed` is the right way to make something stay in one place on a page. It makes more sense to me for it to say `bottom: 0%` and adjust the margin as you need, but like I said, if it works!

Comment: you may want to consider what will happen if the body text is as long as the viewport height. The text might go behind the fixed footer and you may not be able to see it.

Comment: I realize this. Are there any suggestions that will keep it at the bottom, unless it needs to go lower than the bottom?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may want to consider what will happen if the body text is as long as the viewport height. The text might go behind the fixed footer and you may not be able to see it

I would recommend;

```
#footer { 
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -150px; /* negative value of footer height */
    height: 150px;
    clear:both;
}
```

then make sure to give the div wrapping all the content has a padding bottom the same as the height of the footer.

```
#main { padding-bottom: 150px; }  /* must be same height as the footer */
```

Comment: Should I still keep my 'top:100%;' code? When using that, the footer is way to low and I have to scroll down many blank spaces to see it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you do the footer always at the bottom of page. You can replace `footer` with `<div id="footer">...</div>`, but I prefer HTML5 `footer`.

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style>
        body { height: 100%;}
        footer {background: url(http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/sprites.png?v=5); 
                position: fixed; bottom: 0; left: 0; height:115px;width:100%; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <footer>

    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```