# Footer always at the bottom of content, if not enough content at the bottom of viewport

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I read most of the questions that came up for this, but they do not seem to work. These two in particular seemed to be what I was after, but I don't want the footer fixed to the bottom of the viewport.

[How to keep footer always at the bottom of a page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14960467/how-to-keep-footer-always-at-the-bottom-of-a-page)

[How to keep  always at the bottom of page,( not screen) in html5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35848968/how-to-keep-footer-always-at-the-bottom-of-page-not-screen-in-html5)

Here is my HTML. I am building in Laravel 5.3's Blade templating engine, but using Bootstrap:

```css
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-top: 1px solid #d3e0e9;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
  p {
    margin: 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<footer class="footer">
  <div class="container">
    <p>Stuff</p>
  </div>
</footer>
```

EDIT: Attempting to clarify what I am asking here and also removed references above to changing the viewport size. That is cause for confusion and ultimately isn't relevant to what I am asking.

Can take `fixed` off the table for the time being as that won't be a solution: I don't always want the the footer at the bottom of the view port regardless of content.

Assume the viewport is and will always be full screen on a desktop.

Assume first page one has very little content and a footer below the content.

`Relative` leaves an ugly gap between the bottom of the footer and bottom edge of the viewport.

`Absolute` puts it up against the bottom border. This appears to be the correct option for a page with very little content.

Now assume a new page with the same footer, but there is a ton of content with several pages of scrolling in the browser.

`Absolute` (at least when I am using it) tends to stay at the bottom of the viewport and not below the content.

`Relative` will put it below the content and will be the solution for this problem.

But now it won't work with the page with very little content.

It seems like I need a mix of these two, but the only thing that comes to mind is using JQuery, testing if the content goes passed the bottom edge of the viewport. If it does, change the CSS to relative from the default absolute.

Seems like there would be an easier way to accomplish this with just CSS.

Comment: add height to footer and margin to 0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/jxg3c6ue/

If you use relative-absolute position relationship. But I would not advice this way of programming. Media query is the most suitable for your project. However, I just answer on how can it be done in other ways.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body, html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding-bottom: 18px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus lectus justo, consequat non accumsan a, condimentum vel ipsum. Fusce ac leo tristique, fermentum orci a, suscipit massa. Curabitur dignissim metus ligula, sit amet convallis risus elementum quis. Donec in nunc vitae quam vestibulum malesuada nec vitae ipsum. Ut quis nulla elit. Duis luctus dictum aliquet. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Phasellus mollis, tellus quis interdum facilisis, enim ligula pulvinar sem, id congue sapien dui at sapien. Fusce aliquam neque ac justo blandit volutpat. Curabitur et hendrerit tellus. Duis risus massa, commodo id consectetur dapibus, laoreet id ligula.</p>
  <p>Aliquam cursus turpis in quam aliquam pretium. Pellentesque urna est, pulvinar non ultrices a, tincidunt at dolor. Quisque a libero ut nunc commodo pulvinar a ac tortor. Nulla quis faucibus mi. Vivamus tempor mauris id justo bibendum interdum. Ut condimentum tempus ipsum quis finibus. Vivamus ut scelerisque purus, sed condimentum turpis. Nam fermentum sit amet erat ac bibendum.</p>
  <p>Integer quis euismod massa. Morbi ornare ante a risus pharetra tincidunt. Phasellus tincidunt molestie eros, id tristique leo pharetra at. Curabitur pharetra maximus rutrum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla volutpat eget lorem non sollicitudin. Morbi fringilla eget quam nec tempus. Cras id porttitor tortor. Mauris rhoncus rhoncus tincidunt. Nulla facilisi. Mauris tempus dolor ac libero consequat, at commodo ipsum pulvinar. Maecenas ullamcorper lacinia nisi, nec consectetur libero auctor nec. Suspendisse consectetur ex non justo sollicitudin tempor. Curabitur semper, diam et hendrerit molestie, libero quam porta ligula, et viverra velit magna nec lectus. Aliquam nec sem ultrices, gravida lacus eget, scelerisque mauris.</p>
  <p>Sed vitae est eu leo aliquam aliquet id vitae tellus. Donec efficitur, dui vitae mollis interdum, dui purus lobortis nulla, sed egestas enim nulla eu neque. Fusce placerat nisi quis nisi dictum egestas. Pellentesque vel convallis nulla. Donec ac nisi at nibh aliquam congue finibus id mi. Morbi pulvinar laoreet massa sed aliquet. Cras efficitur, sapien vel gravida ultricies, nisi tellus mollis est, sed faucibus quam justo vehicula metus. Nunc vulputate nulla quis lectus fermentum egestas. Nunc fermentum sapien ut ex fringilla imperdiet. Vestibulum quis mi vel tellus pretium commodo. Praesent nulla elit, viverra ac efficitur at, euismod sed dui. Ut a leo nec arcu tempus ultricies eu ac ipsum. Nunc vulputate eu nulla quis pharetra. Nunc iaculis, nibh congue vulputate tincidunt, arcu nisl vestibulum mi, at rutrum ipsum neque non augue. In augue dolor, imperdiet eu faucibus non, mattis at ipsum. Nulla facilisi.</p>
  <p>Quisque fringilla non sem eget faucibus. Cras nec nulla sit amet est cursus efficitur. Proin euismod nibh ut arcu maximus maximus. Nunc consectetur libero ac enim imperdiet, luctus tincidunt magna aliquam. Donec eleifend porttitor pretium. Nullam urna nisl, facilisis id pretium et, commodo ut neque. In id elit urna. Vivamus tincidunt est sed ligula condimentum sagittis. In vel lobortis diam. In nulla sem, dictum a nisl vitae, pretium malesuada felis.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus lectus justo, consequat non accumsan a, condimentum vel ipsum. Fusce ac leo tristique, fermentum orci a, suscipit massa. Curabitur dignissim metus ligula, sit amet convallis risus elementum quis. Donec in nunc vitae quam vestibulum malesuada nec vitae ipsum. Ut quis nulla elit. Duis luctus dictum aliquet. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Phasellus mollis, tellus quis interdum facilisis, enim ligula pulvinar sem, id congue sapien dui at sapien. Fusce aliquam neque ac justo blandit volutpat. Curabitur et hendrerit tellus. Duis risus massa, commodo id consectetur dapibus, laoreet id ligula.</p>
  <p>Aliquam cursus turpis in quam aliquam pretium. Pellentesque urna est, pulvinar non ultrices a, tincidunt at dolor. Quisque a libero ut nunc commodo pulvinar a ac tortor. Nulla quis faucibus mi. Vivamus tempor mauris id justo bibendum interdum. Ut condimentum tempus ipsum quis finibus. Vivamus ut scelerisque purus, sed condimentum turpis. Nam fermentum sit amet erat ac bibendum.</p>
  <p>Integer quis euismod massa. Morbi ornare ante a risus pharetra tincidunt. Phasellus tincidunt molestie eros, id tristique leo pharetra at. Curabitur pharetra maximus rutrum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla volutpat eget lorem non sollicitudin. Morbi fringilla eget quam nec tempus. Cras id porttitor tortor. Mauris rhoncus rhoncus tincidunt. Nulla facilisi. Mauris tempus dolor ac libero consequat, at commodo ipsum pulvinar. Maecenas ullamcorper lacinia nisi, nec consectetur libero auctor nec. Suspendisse consectetur ex non justo sollicitudin tempor. Curabitur semper, diam et hendrerit molestie, libero quam porta ligula, et viverra velit magna nec lectus. Aliquam nec sem ultrices, gravida lacus eget, scelerisque mauris.</p>
  <p>Sed vitae est eu leo aliquam aliquet id vitae tellus. Donec efficitur, dui vitae mollis interdum, dui purus lobortis nulla, sed egestas enim nulla eu neque. Fusce placerat nisi quis nisi dictum egestas. Pellentesque vel convallis nulla. Donec ac nisi at nibh aliquam congue finibus id mi. Morbi pulvinar laoreet massa sed aliquet. Cras efficitur, sapien vel gravida ultricies, nisi tellus mollis est, sed faucibus quam justo vehicula metus. Nunc vulputate nulla quis lectus fermentum egestas. Nunc fermentum sapien ut ex fringilla imperdiet. Vestibulum quis mi vel tellus pretium commodo. Praesent nulla elit, viverra ac efficitur at, euismod sed dui. Ut a leo nec arcu tempus ultricies eu ac ipsum. Nunc vulputate eu nulla quis pharetra. Nunc iaculis, nibh congue vulputate tincidunt, arcu nisl vestibulum mi, at rutrum ipsum neque non augue. In augue dolor, imperdiet eu faucibus non, mattis at ipsum. Nulla facilisi.</p>
  <p>Quisque fringilla non sem eget faucibus. Cras nec nulla sit amet est cursus efficitur. Proin euismod nibh ut arcu maximus maximus. Nunc consectetur libero ac enim imperdiet, luctus tincidunt magna aliquam. Donec eleifend porttitor pretium. Nullam urna nisl, facilisis id pretium et, commodo ut neque. In id elit urna. Vivamus tincidunt est sed ligula condimentum sagittis. In vel lobortis diam. In nulla sem, dictum a nisl vitae, pretium malesuada felis.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus lectus justo, consequat non accumsan a, condimentum vel ipsum. Fusce ac leo tristique, fermentum orci a, suscipit massa. Curabitur dignissim metus ligula, sit amet convallis risus elementum quis. Donec in nunc vitae quam vestibulum malesuada nec vitae ipsum. Ut quis nulla elit. Duis luctus dictum aliquet. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Phasellus mollis, tellus quis interdum facilisis, enim ligula pulvinar sem, id congue sapien dui at sapien. Fusce aliquam neque ac justo blandit volutpat. Curabitur et hendrerit tellus. Duis risus massa, commodo id consectetur dapibus, laoreet id ligula.</p>
  <p>Aliquam cursus turpis in quam aliquam pretium. Pellentesque urna est, pulvinar non ultrices a, tincidunt at dolor. Quisque a libero ut nunc commodo pulvinar a ac tortor. Nulla quis faucibus mi. Vivamus tempor mauris id justo bibendum interdum. Ut condimentum tempus ipsum quis finibus. Vivamus ut scelerisque purus, sed condimentum turpis. Nam fermentum sit amet erat ac bibendum.</p>
  <p>Integer quis euismod massa. Morbi ornare ante a risus pharetra tincidunt. Phasellus tincidunt molestie eros, id tristique leo pharetra at. Curabitur pharetra maximus rutrum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla volutpat eget lorem non sollicitudin. Morbi fringilla eget quam nec tempus. Cras id porttitor tortor. Mauris rhoncus rhoncus tincidunt. Nulla facilisi. Mauris tempus dolor ac libero consequat, at commodo ipsum pulvinar. Maecenas ullamcorper lacinia nisi, nec consectetur libero auctor nec. Suspendisse consectetur ex non justo sollicitudin tempor. Curabitur semper, diam et hendrerit molestie, libero quam porta ligula, et viverra velit magna nec lectus. Aliquam nec sem ultrices, gravida lacus eget, scelerisque mauris.</p>
  <p>Sed vitae est eu leo aliquam aliquet id vitae tellus. Donec efficitur, dui vitae mollis interdum, dui purus lobortis nulla, sed egestas enim nulla eu neque. Fusce placerat nisi quis nisi dictum egestas. Pellentesque vel convallis nulla. Donec ac nisi at nibh aliquam congue finibus id mi. Morbi pulvinar laoreet massa sed aliquet. Cras efficitur, sapien vel gravida ultricies, nisi tellus mollis est, sed faucibus quam justo vehicula metus. Nunc vulputate nulla quis lectus fermentum egestas. Nunc fermentum sapien ut ex fringilla imperdiet. Vestibulum quis mi vel tellus pretium commodo. Praesent nulla elit, viverra ac efficitur at, euismod sed dui. Ut a leo nec arcu tempus ultricies eu ac ipsum. Nunc vulputate eu nulla quis pharetra. Nunc iaculis, nibh congue vulputate tincidunt, arcu nisl vestibulum mi, at rutrum ipsum neque non augue. In augue dolor, imperdiet eu faucibus non, mattis at ipsum. Nulla facilisi.</p>
  <p>Quisque fringilla non sem eget faucibus. Cras nec nulla sit amet est cursus efficitur. Proin euismod nibh ut arcu maximus maximus. Nunc consectetur libero ac enim imperdiet, luctus tincidunt magna aliquam. Donec eleifend porttitor pretium. Nullam urna nisl, facilisis id pretium et, commodo ut neque. In id elit urna. Vivamus tincidunt est sed ligula condimentum sagittis. In vel lobortis diam. In nulla sem, dictum a nisl vitae, pretium malesuada felis.</p>
</div>

<footer>
  this is a footer
</footer>
```

Without content

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body, html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding-bottom: 18px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
  
</div>

<footer>
  this is a footer
</footer>
```

Comment: Hi added the `body, html` selectors since I already had the `footer` selectors you have. However, the footer now sits over the content in the case of the little content page.

Comment: @ishraqiyun77 hmmmm. I think some of your style breaking the code. If you see the demo. It's working :)

Comment: Yea, not sure. Definitely works in yours. All I have in my CSS though is what I posted above. Pretty clean at the moment.

Comment: @ishraqiyun77 put it on fiddle. So, I can check it :D

Comment: Sorry, here is the fiddle. Looks somewhat close to what I am working on, but at least the problem is being reproduced so you can see what I am seeing: https://jsfiddle.net/7kopcqxz/

Comment: Oh man, I added the `min-height: 100vh` and that answered my question. Oversight on my part as I just added the `position: relative` for the `body, html` selectors. Thanks!

Comment: @ishraqiyun77 Glad I helped :D Too happy you got it :) See you around again.

Answer (score 0):

There are some good difference between absolute and fixed positioning. You should definitely google it to understand better. Meanwhile in short absolute positioning is done respective of the parent relative / absolute position.

I'm not clear about question since it's too wage to read. Hoping that you are looking something like. Footer always stay bottom to the viewport.

```css
.viewFooter{
  background:#ddd;
  color:#3d3d3d;
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  font-size:16px;
  text-align:center;
  padding:10px
}
body{
  margin:0;
  height:calc(1000px - 40px);
  position:relative
}
```

```html
<div class="viewFooter">
  This will be positioned at the bottom of the view Port
</div>
```

Footer staying at the bottom of viewport

```css
.pageFooter{
  background:#ddd;
  color:#3d3d3d;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  font-size:16px;
  text-align:center;
  padding:10px
}
body{
  margin:0;
  height:1000px;
  position:relative
}
```

```html
<div class="pageFooter">
  This will be positioned at the bottom of the page
</div>
```

If you want to switch between absolute and fixed position in different viewport. use media queries. The above given will switch to absolute positioning in mobile devices

```css
.viewFooter{
  background:#ddd;
  color:#3d3d3d;
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  font-size:16px;
  text-align:center;
  padding:10px
}
body{
  margin:0;
  height:1000px;
  position:relative
}
@media only screen 
  and (max-width: 600px) {
    .viewFooter{
      position:absolute;
    }
  }
```

```html
<div class="viewFooter">
  This will be positioned at the bottom of the view Port
</div>
```

Make sure the footer div is directly appended to body tag.

Comment: The crux of what I am after is the last sentence primarily. Not phrased the best way. Basically if I have a browser full screen, and leave it as such, I want the footer to be at the bottom edge of the view port if there is not enough content on the page because I don't want an ugly gap below the footer. Still leaving it at full screen, if there is enough content to push the footer passed the bottom of view port, the footer just comes after the content. First example is `absolute` the second is `relative`, correct? All this without changing viewport size. JS? Take `fixed` off table, not needed.